# How to install jpegrescan on Centos 6?

Tags: linux, path, jpeg, centos6, image-compression

Id like to use jpegrescan on my Centos 6 linux install, both on its own and as part of Picopt.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it work with either. The Picopt instructions just vaguely say it needs to be "in path" though I'm not sure where that is?

I've tried dropping in various places such as /usr/bin /usr/local/bin - but I don't get the jpegrescan command, and nor does picopt find it to use...

Can anyone advise?

Comment: did you make `jpegrescan` executable?

Comment: I didn't no, i tried to do something with perl as its a perl script but 'perl jpegrescan' just throws the error
Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at jpegrescan line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at jpegrescan line 5.

Comment: Just ran "chmod +x jpegrescan" but still no change.

There is literally nothing online about installing it/using it for linux/centos :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the `jpegrescan` Perl script and making it executable, you also need to install the `File::Slurp` Perl module like so:

```
yum install perl-File-Slurp
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, the command needed was:

```
apt-get -y install libfile-slurp-perl
```

So complete installation sequence in Ubuntu would be:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libfile-slurp-perl
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kud/jpegrescan/master/jpegrescan -O /usr/local/bin/jpegrescan
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/jpegrescan
```